# Selenium is not able to click on window pop up when VM is minimize.

Tags: java, selenium, virtual-machine

My script(Selenium-java) is not able to click on Window pop up during download and upload Test Cases when VM is minimize.

This test case is working perfectly on the local machine as well as on Virtual machine only when the focus remains on browser.

Comment: Virtual machine is minimized? You mean while browser is minimized?

Comment: Do you have different browser version in VM?

Comment: @Chris311 - Browser remains open. I work on local machine after minimize Virtual machine.

Comment: @ShubhamJain- I am working on company project. In Project I am using IE-9 browser.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced that *Firefox* is **suppressing events** so that (at least some) JavaScripts from the webpage will not be executed when that window has not the focus which seems to be an optimization.
In this case I used to bring back the focus by switching to the window:

```
Browser.WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(Browser.WebDriver.CurrentWindowHandle);
```

Check at which point and why the foucs changes *unintentionally*.

If you open a number of browser windows for one test it might be useful to **"manage"** - keep track of and switch between them - to keep the focus. 
Furthermore it could help to restore/maximize the window.

Using **SeleniumGRID** could solve this and some other problems during test execution, because tests are getting executed (more) isolated.

Answer (score 1):

This IE-specific issue is summarised very well, here:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/why-does-ie9-running-webdriver-scripts-gets-out-of-focus-if-other-applications-a

There doesn't seem to be a solution, only workarounds, the consensus being: **don't** run IE on a minimised VM.

> The only workaround we've been able to do is run the tests at night
>   when there is nothing else going on [...]

Or:

> [...] run it on a separate VM from my development box. This allows me
>   to both keep working on my existing code plus eliminate interaction
>   issues. I also am able to then keep the VM from sleeping etc and have
>   pretty discrete control on that box.

Comment: Hi, please "accept" this answer (green tick) if it helped you solve your problem - thanks!